# Efficiently composing promise tests

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, bluebird

I find myself often writing tests for async APIs like this:

```
beforeEach(function(done) {
  setup()
  .then(function(val) {
    return setup2();
  })
  .done(done, done);
});

it('should test something', function(done) {
  promiseFunction
  .then(function(val) {
    expect(val).to.be.something;
  })
  .done(done, done);
});
```

Which seems pretty straightforward, except for the beforeEach function: if setup2 returns a promise, then done will be called with a value, which it doesn't like.  So I end up having to write:

```
.done(function() { done(); }, done)
```

which is all well and good, but I'm wondering if there's a more compact way to do this (yes, I'm lazy!).  Like

```
.catch(done) //handle fail
.then(null)  //strip the promise value
.then(done)  //handle success
```

but `then` requires a function.  I know a trivial solution is to write myself another function:

```
function noParam(done) { done(); }
```

and use:

```
.done(noParam(done), done);
```

I'm just wondering if there's a better way to compose this generally or a way to use existing API functions.

Comment: Please do not add the solution to your question. If you've come up with something that improves of the solution you accepted, then you can submit it as a formal answer. Thank you.

Comment: If that's policy, np.  But removing a clarification of what worked and didn't work is unnecessarily obfuscating the solution for future users, imho.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `done` uses node callback conventions, you'll want to have a look at the [`.asCallback`](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#ascallbackfunction-callback--object-options---promise) method. You might do

```
beforeEach(function(done) {
  setup()
  .then(function(val) {
    return setup2();
  })
  .asCallback(done);
});
```

And mocha (unless you are using very old version) supports returning promises so your test code can be written as:

```
it('should test something', function() {
  return promiseFunction
  .then(function(val) {
    expect(val).to.be.something;
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Esailija, but if you had posted this as a standalone answer I could've given you an upvote for it :-)

Comment: Great, thanks.  ```.asCallback``` almost but not quite kills it.  But mocha promises, whee!